# Find min cut in network flow

Tags: algorithm, networking

We can use DFS/BFS starting from source to find a min cut. But can we use BFS/DFS starting from each node to see if it can reach to sink to find a min cut?
Or, how do we find all minimum cuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I understood your question. In order to find a min cut we can find the max flow and use it to find the min cut (by the min cut max flow theorem).

If you want to check if there is more than one min cut, after you get the residual network, run `BFS(s)`- starting at `s`, let this group of vertices be `X`. Then flip the edges of the residual network and run `BFS(t)`, let this group of vertices be `Y`. if the union of `X` and `Y` are all the vertices of the graph, you have only one cut. Else- you have more than one (in order to find all the `Z` min cut, it will take at least `(Z|V|)`